elements in <p-splitter> won't detect screen size changes
I'm using a <p-splitter> and inside the areas of the splitter I use some responsive grids in PrimeNG. The thing is when I resize those areas the components inside them won't notice the size change in the splitter area ...  but if I resize the screen, they will. Is there some workaround to avoid this situation?

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated
